# WinHttp.WinHttpRequest in .NET

Tags: .net, winhttp, winhttprequest

Is there a built-in .NET class that can replace or work like WinHttp.WinHttpRequest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the **System.Net.HttpRequest** class:

[HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

Provides an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.

- Namespace:  System.Net
- Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

You can alternatively use the **System.Net.WebClient** class:

[WebClient Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Provides common methods for sending data to and receiving data from a resource identified by a URI.

- Namespace:  System.Net
- Assembly:  System (in System.dll)

This class simplifies some common tasks, like downloading a file (method `DownloadFile`)

> The WebClient class provides common
>   methods for sending data to or
>   receiving data from any local,
>   intranet, or Internet resource
>   identified by a URI.
>
> The WebClient class uses the
>   WebRequest class to provide access to
>   resources. WebClient instances can
>   access data with any WebRequest
>   descendant registered with the
>   WebRequest.RegisterPrefix method.

Comment: Thanks! I think i'll be using the WebClient class to upload text files. I've created some codes for the upload and it seems to be uploading the files because the UploadFile method executes without any exception, but i still have to find where the files are being uploaded. Any ideas?

Comment: The files are uploaded to the URI you provide. you should check the server implementation (form handling). WebClient does the client part. I hope this helps.